# Kakeya sets on surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

In the plane, a Kakeya set is a set of points that contains unit line segments in every direction. Let's define a Kakeya set on an open surface (with a complete metric) to be a set that contains unit length geodesics in every direction. Here, by two geodesics having the same direction, we imply that they stay at finite distance from each other.

Clearly, there are Kakeya sets on any surface: If $\gamma$ is a geodesic so that $d(\gamma(t),x) \rightarrow \infty$, then by taking a sequence of geodesics connecting $x$ to $\gamma(t)$ and deriving a convergent subsequence, we can obtain a geodesic through $x$ in the direction of $\gamma(t)$.

Question: On the plane, there are Kakeya sets of measure zero. Can one construct Kakeya sets of measure zero on any surface as well?

Comment: I don't see why not.  One could stereographically project the standard fractal example from the plane to obtain such things in $S^2$ for example.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "every direction"?  Are two directed geodesic segments declared to have the same direction if their extensions to geodesic rays have finite hausdorff distance?

Comment: Richard, I think my following definition is equivalent to yours: two geodesic segments have the same direction if for extensions $\gamma(t)$ and $\eta(t)$ of them, we have $\forall t: d(\gamma(t),\eta(t))\leq C$ for a constant $C$ independent of $t$. 

Comment: Glen, note that for $S^2$ or any closed surface, the question is not interesting since every two geodesics have the same direction. In the noncompact case, it is not clear to me how one can project the standard example; for example wouldn't the nontrivial topology complicate things? 

Comment: When you say geodesic do you mean complete geodesic or a geodesic ray? Note that in the hyperbolic plane two complete geodesics are within finite distance iff they are the same up to parameterization. 

Comment: You also have to assume that your surface is simply-connected and has nonpositive curvature. Otherwise, construction of a geodesic ray in the given direction through the given point fails. (Distances between segments connecting $x$ to $\gamma(T)$ and the segment $\gamma(t), 0\le t\le T$, can diverge to infinity as $T\to\infty$.)  

Comment: As Misha says, your question has sense for open complete surfaces with negative curvature. If in addition the curvature is negatively pinched, then existence of Kakeya set of arbitrary small area follows from the fact that there are triangles with arbitrary small sum of angles. Simply take three unit sectors at the vertices of this such triangle.

Comment: Misha, I do mean geodesic rays. You are right that we need nonpositive curvature in the argument I mentioned. 

Comment: Anton, that's a nice example.


Comment: I wasn't thinking of the same definition of 'same direction'.  For example, on $S^2$ again, if we take two great circles which meet at the poles and consider a subset of the equatorial line perpendicular to both, I would say that these two geodesics are *not* in the 'same direction'.  This seems to not be as natural as I thought however.